# Unique Identifier of MySQL installation

Tags: mysql

I want to know if there is a unique key that identifies the installation of mysql server on a computer, a key or id that does not repeat per computer.

Comment: check out server_uuid at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a Key or ID that is given and not set by any user.

Comment: It helps if you read the docs... "In MySQL 5.7, the server generates a true UUID in addition to the --server-id supplied by the user. This is available as the global, read-only variable server_uuid."

Comment: Damn you are right!!! thanks for the help